# Change script file extension in Apps Script online IDE

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, ide

I've created a script using Apps Script in Google Sheets, and would like to code in TypeScript.  I gather to do this you need to rename the default `.gs` file to `.ts`.

**How does one accomplish that in the online IDE?**  It doesn't seem to let you rename the extension:

[image: Animation showing a rename attempt from Code.js to Code.ts producing Code.ts.js]

I tried the "classic editor" with similar results.  I don't want to install Node (which requires Administrator privileges) and CLASP (which requires granting access to my Google account) just to rename a file!

There are hints the online editor supports TypeScript (e.g. autocomplete lists parameter types):

[image: Example of autocomplete showing typed parameters]

But if I try creating typed variables or parameters in my `.gs` file I get linter and syntax errors:

[image: let foo:string = 'hello';]

[image: Syntax error Unexpected token ':']

Comment: That differ effect is doing my head in.

Comment: You do know that the Google App Script editor is for javascript? Except for HTML Service files which are HTML.

Comment: @TheWizEd are you saying the online editor will happily parse and show you parameter types for library functions but break down if you open a .ts file and use them in your own functions?

Comment: No I'm saying it probably doesn't understand some of the typescript syntax, unless its purely javascript.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this article [Develop Apps Script using TypeScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript)

Comment: @TheWizEd - I did read that article, but it doesn't indicate whether the online editor supports TypeScript.  Maybe someone who already has a `.ts` file in their project could try opening it in the IDE and see what happens?

Comment: Apps Script is JavaScript rather than TypeScript. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is currently not supported in Apps script editor. There is however, a feature request for the same here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238057231

You may add a +1 or comment in the tracker explaining benefits from a business point of view, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks.  I wish they were clearer about that.  I assumed it was supported because it was showing up in the autocomplete.